# Change frame rate without changing film speed/duration

Tags: ffmpeg

I've made a mistake and I need to re-encode video from 30 fps to 24fps, while maintaining the same speed/duration.

Does anyone know how I might do this in FFMPEG?

I've tried changing the -r value and this changes the rate, but changes the video length.

Thanks

Comment: Show the full command you used.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To change the frame rate without modifying the total length of the video, FFmpeg has to duplicate or drop some frames. Unfortunately this process can turn a steady smooth movemen to become clumsy and unnatural in the video.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -r 24 -y output.mov
```

This method is very slow so be patient. The audio will remain the same, since length does not change.

You can also check this tool if your results are not what you expected: [MVTools](http://avisynth.org.ru/mvtools/mvtools.html#examples)

Here is a thread that may be helpful [Change framerate in ffmpeg without re-encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/1088382/change-framerate-in-ffmpeg-without-reencoding)

Comment: `-sameq` has been removed from `ffmpeg` a long time ago and [never meant "same quality"](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#Why-was-the-ffmpeg-_002dsameq-option-removed_003f-What-to-use-instead_003f). For encoding with x264 use `-crf` instead.

Comment: Also, without using a filter, ffmpeg does not interpolate frames. It either duplicates or drops them.

Comment: @Gyan You write 'It either duplicates or drops them.'. May I ask where you get this information? Because the process is taking awfully long for just duplicating or dropping frames.

Comment: In case it is not 'only' dropping frames or duplicating them, how do we ensure that the quality of the original video is conserved?

Answer (score 2):

This command won't change the video playback speed:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -filter:v fps=fps=30 <output>
```

Worked well for reducing fps from 59.6 to 30.