# ffmpeg framerate conform without re-encoding, like apple's cinema tools?

Tags: ffmpeg

i've seen similar questions but nothing this subtle, such a slight change. also, nothing i've tried so far has proved reliable for this whereas using cinema tools has always been reliable (i'll explain below). all i need to do is change a video's framerate from 23.976fps to 24fps. cinema tools does this by simply changing something(s) in the file header so the change does not require making a new file or more than a second, even for large files. is there an ffmpeg way of doing this?

for anyone interested, i'm making dcp files from quicktime mov files. the dcp process requires 24fps material. when i make conversions of 23.976fps material and extract the audio to put it into opendcp, the dcp-making software i like, the audio always shows an incorrect length. this does not happen if i work directly from 24fps files. for that reason and, having used cinema tools in the past for these conversions (no longer available to me now), i want to simply conform all of my 23.976fps files to 24fps and do so without doubling my disk space and time consumed.

thanks very much for any answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change framerate in ffmpeg without reencoding](https://superuser.com/questions/1088382/change-framerate-in-ffmpeg-without-reencoding)

Comment: Show the complete output of `ffmpeg -i input.mov`

Answer (score 0):

ok, do you want to change the frame rate?, if you have 23.976fps to 24fps yo have to use filter video (-vf), some like this

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf fps=fps=24 output.mp4
```

if you have another question, type first the data of the input file, typing

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4
```

NOTE: if you work in windows or mac, check the manual for the codes, but the structure is the same.

and type your dude with this dates.

Comment: I always use the -r parameter to change the frame rate so like this:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 24 output.mp4
This works really well but the -vf option might work as well.

Comment: thanks for the answers. looks like either the -vf or -r methods will apply the changes to a new file. is that right? is there really no way to simply alter a header or something? a new file can take a lot of time and disk space. some of my files are hundreds of gb in size. also, wouldn't some kind of codec copy option be necessary to prevent interpolating new frames or dropping frames depending on the rate change? i'd want to preserve the same number of frames as the original file, just change how fast the system plays it. thanks again.

Comment: @user1133964 1) Using filters requires re-encoding, so this answer does not copy the stream only.
2) `ffmpeg` will have to create a new file: it can't edit a file in-place.

Comment: this wouldn't be fast or diskspace efficient but what about extracting the separate video and audio streams from the mov container and then remuxing them back into another mov container with a new frame rate? would that work without a re-encode? what would that command look like? thanks.

Comment: ffmpeg ever have to create a new file, it was think for streaming live.

Comment: can you upload this video to mediafire to show in a example how to do this job?