# MP4 file has very high frame rate

Tags: video, framerate

I recently downloaded some video files via player.vimeo.com.
They are in mp4 format, about 50 minutes long.
The Windows 11 file manager properties says the frame rates are very high, like 15,272 fps.

When I try to play the files using either the Windows media player or VLC,
the video portion plays very fast and completes in a few seconds, but the audio plays at the normal rate.

I have tried several online video conversion services, setting the frame rate to 30 fps,
but the result is the same as the original file.

Here is the output from ffprobe on one of the files:

```
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
Duration: 00:49:18.14, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 668 kb/s
Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 
48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : Vimeo Isopod Audio Handler
vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), 
yuv420p(tv, smpte170m, progressive), 
960x540, 242454 kb/s, 15272.12 fps, 15360 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

Any ideas on how to change the video frame rate from 15,272 to 30,
without changing the audio rate?

Comment: Try using FFmpeg: `ffmpeg -r 30 -i input.mp4 -vf setpts=N/30/TB -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4`. Note that this is not the best solution because it re-encodes the video. In should be possible to modify the video timestamps without re-encoding.

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1088382/change-framerate-in-ffmpeg-without-reencoding) help ?

Comment: Thanks. That worked great! I'm a noobie at this. The documentation for setpts does not make much sense to me. Can you explain about setpts=N/30/TB?  THANKS

Comment: I did some more looking and found a way to change the frame rate without encoding:  
<https://superuser.com/questions/1088382/change-framerate-in-ffmpeg-without-reencoding>  
Here is the command:  
    `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -bsf:v setts=ts=STARTPTS+N/TB_OUT/30 -codec: copy output.mp4`